# How to change the style of an environment

Tags: definition

> How would I display my definition as 
>   **Definition 1.1 (Flow map)^1.** (^1 is meant to be superscript and denotes a footnote).

This is my code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%enviorment
\newtheorem{defn}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}

\newtheorem{flow}[defn]{definition}
\begin{flow}[\bf{Flow map}{\footnote{\citet[p. \ 9]{barreira}}}]
%text
\end{flow}

\begin{thebibliography}
%items
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

which gives me

**Definition 1.1 (Flow map^1).**

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Thanks for showing us some of your code, but please add a complete minimal working example, which will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Are you sure your readers would interpret correctly the superscript to the parenthesis?

Comment: See \textsuperscript.